# Move a widget on to another widget? (Wordpress/HTML/CSS)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Im new in wordpress.   I have a "Search Widget" and "Image Slider Widget"  and i want to move the search widget on to slider.

When I try to move, the 'Search Widget' goes under of image

[image]

Comment: This needs more info. Are you writing your own theme, or modifying one you downloaded? Did you build the slider, or is it a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS and `position: absolute`, and move it with `margin`.
For example:

```
.the-widget
{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -240px;
}
```

For the Search Widget that is.
Then, if the Search Widget goes under the image, play around with the widgets' `z-index`. The greater this value is, the higher up the element will be rendered.